# JavaScript String split method delimiter

Tags: javascript, split, delimiter

For an assignment, I'm trying to split a phone number in the following format: (555) 555-5555 into 2 pieces. The first is the Area code which should display "555" and the second is the remaining number which should display "555-5555".

I've managed to get answers to display almost perfectly, except the area code displays as "(555)" instead of "555" which is what I need.

How do I make the delimiter look for the numbers in between the parenthesis?

Here's my current code:

```
function splitButtonPressed()
{
   var inputString = document.getElementById( "inputField" ).value; //Input field for numbers
   var tokens1 = inputString.split( " " ); 


   document.getElementById("areaOutput").value = tokens1[0]; 

   document.getElementById("numberOutput").value = tokens1[1];
}
```

EDIT: I've got it to work, Thank You all for your help.

Comment: string.substr(1, string.length -1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementById("areaOutput").value = tokens1[0];
```

to

```
document.getElementById("areaOutput").value = tokens1[0].substr(1, 3);
```

What the above code does is grabs a substring from `tokens1[0]` starting at the first character in the string and grabbing the three characters after that (5, 5, and 5).

Comment: I will accept the answer in 4 min (Won't let me do it now).

Also, I can't upvote. Don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to use `.split()` to solve this problem and you want to allow a bunch of different delimiters for the area code, I'd probably do this using a regular expression:

```
var phoneStr = "(123) 456-7890";
var match = phoneStr.match(/\s*\(?(\d+)[)\-\s]\s*(\d+)[\s*\-](\d+)/);

// areaCode = match[1];
// prefix = match[2];
// num = match[3];​
```

Here's a test app that shows it working on a bunch of different phone numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/L87rE/

Here's how the regex works:

```
Any amount of whitespace  \s*
An optional left paren    \(?
A series of digits (captured for match[1])   (\d+)
Any one of several delimiters a right paren, a dash or whitespace  [)\-\s]
Any amount of whitespace   \s*
A series of digits (captured for match[2])   (\d+)
Whitespace or dash as a delimiter   [\s*\-]
A series of digits (captured for match[3])   (\d+)/
```

Comment: I have to use .split for this assignment. It's part of the requirement. Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using a single `.split()` that works on a flexible phone number format like these:

```
"(123) 456-7890",
"123-456-7890",
" (123)456-7890",
" 123 456 7890"

var phoneStr = "(123) 456-7890";
// precondition the phone number by removing parens and trimming extra whitespace
var str = phoneStr.replace(/[\(\)]/g, " ").replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
// split on either a dash or whitespace
var parts = str.split(/-|\s+/);
// areacode == parts[0]
// prefix == parts[1]
// num == parts[2]
```

Test cases here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UUgXM/

To make the `.split()` operation generate consistent results with varying formats, it uses a couple `.replace()` operations to precondition the input before the `.split()`.

This uses a regex with the `.split()` so a single split can split on more than one thing.

Comment: Unlike the pure-regex solution, I can actually read the code here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `match()`:

```
document.getElementById("areaOutput").value = tokens1[0].match(/\d+/);
```

Comment: Although that's an elegant solution, the OP wouldn't need to use a Regex in this case, as his input will be a static number. E.g. the positions of the digits will never change.